# Query returns no records to show on my webpage

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, ms-access

I've got a website where I'm running the following code:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON  Table2.ID=BlogEntryItems.BlogID WHERE ([Table2.ID]=@ID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="Table2.ID" Type="Decimal" />                    
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

It seems to return no records, although I have run the query in Access and it returns the records I'm expecting. Note: In my query in Access, I substituted

```
WHERE ([Table2.ID]=@ID)
```

with

```
WHERE Table2.ID=4
```

Comment: and you are positive that your querystringparameter `ID` has the value 4?

Comment: It did before I added the join statement.

Comment: Also, it needs to be that it returns the value of the record of Table 2 that was clicked to pass into the QueryString request.

Answer (score 0):

Make the query in your code exactly the same as the one you're running against Access. (Replace `@ID` with `4`.)
If it returns the records you expect, the problem is with `@ID`.

If it still appears to return no records, then your problem is either with how you're sending your command to the database or how you're reading the results.

Comment: Do you get records with the join when running the query in Access?

Comment: I do, that's why it is confusing. Here is the SELECT statement I ran in Access:

     SELECT * FROM Table2 INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON Table2.ID = BlogEntryItems.BlogID
    WHERE Table2.ID=4;

Comment: Are you sure you're running the queries against the same database? If so, try to get a very simple query to work first. For example, `SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ID=4`. If that works, add the join, and make sure it still works, then the parameter instead of the hard-coded id.

Comment: I've been able to get it to run without the join, where it just catches records from Table 2.