# My query works in Access, but not in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have a query that I have run in Access that doesn't seem to run when I execute it on my website site. Here's the code for the webpage that I want the database to populate content for:

```
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
                        DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON Table2.ID=BlogEntryItems.BlogID AND Table2.ID=@ID">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="Table2.ID" Type="Decimal" />                    
                        </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:AccessDataSource>

    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" 
            runat="server" ItemStyle-CssClass="picTableStyle"
            DataKeyField="Table.2ID">
            <ItemStyle></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                         <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("Image") %>' /><br />
                         <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="picCaptionStyle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Caption") %>' />
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label4" class="picBodyText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PicStory") %>' />
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:DataList>
```

When I take out the join, it works fine. I add the join and it doesn't give me any error or anything, it just seems as though there are no results for it to show on my website. Any ideas?

Comment: You already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18284779/138938

Comment: Yeah, is there a way to refresh so more people will look at it? That's the only reason I reposted it.

Comment: @Joseph: What querystring parameter are you using?  Can you post a sample?

Comment: @ajax81, I think you might be asking what is the data type is being passed? It's an autonumber field.

Comment: Otherwise, I'm not sure what you are askin.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I haven't worked on `AccessDataSource`. However, looking at the docs - here is what you should look into

- Change the query to use ? instead of @ID
  `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON Table2.ID=BlogEntryItems.BlogID AND Table2.ID= ?"`

> Because the AccessDataSource control extends the SqlDataSource class
>   and uses the System.Data.OleDb provider, you specify parameter
>   placeholders using the "?" placeholder character.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e5545e1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

- If the above doesn't work, omit the data type (`Decimal`) of the parameter OR specify a relevant type such as `Integer` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input man. When I was using the query without the join clause, "@ID" worked. Nevertheless, I tried your suggestions and none of them worked. It's getting pretty frustrating trying to figure it out. No matter what I do, it seems to return no results, although the query works perfectly in Access...